# Cambiar el tamaño de las barras generadas por facet_grid en R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estoy intentando personalizar una gráfica en Rstudio pero no me deja ampliar el tamaño de las cajas con texto de cada grid generado por facet_grid:

```
dev.off()
   library(showtext)
   showtext_auto()
   theme_set(theme_void(base_family = "Bebas Neue")) # Definir tema base


   theme_update(
     text=element_text(family="Helvetica", size=13),
     strip.background = element_rect(
       color="black", fill="#e2ecf1", size=1.5, linetype="solid"),
     strip.text.x = element_text(
       size = 13, color = "black", face = "bold"),
     strip.text.y = element_text(
       size = 13, color = "black", face = "bold"),

     panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white",
                              colour = "black",
                              size = 0.5, linetype = "solid"),
     panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.1, linetype = 'dotted',
                              colour = "lightgrey"),  
legend.position = "top",
legend.key.width = unit(1.65,"cm"),
legend.title = element_blank(),
legend.text =element_text(
size = 13, color = "black", face = "bold"))


   library(harrypotter)
   ggplot(values.graph2, aes(x = tiempo, y = mean),color = tiempo) +
     geom_col(aes(fill = tiempo), alpha = 1)+
     scale_fill_hp_d(option = "Ravenclaw", name = "Clarity") +
     facet_grid(Tipo_mutación~Var, scales = "free")+
     scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.2)),
                 breaks = seq(0,100, by = 20),
                 limits = c(0, 100)) +
     geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sd, ymax=mean+sd), width=.2,
            position=position_dodge(.9)) +
     geom_text(aes(label = sprintf("%0.1f",round(mean,digits = 1))), size = 6,
        position = position_dodge(0.85), vjust = -0.5)+
     geom_hline(yintercept = 0, colour="black", linetype = "solid",size=0.5)
```

Obteniendo este gráfico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podeis ver, donde aparece IMC % number of cycles atb, etc... no aparece con suficiente espacio. ¿Cómo puedo ampliarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo he cambiado los margenes en strip.text. Te pongo un ejemplo:

```
 strip.text.x = element_text(size = 13, 
                          color = "black", 
                          face = "bold",
                          margin = unit(c(4,10,4,10), "points")),
strip.text.y = element_text(size = 13, 
                          color = "black", 
                          face = "bold",
                          margin = unit(c(4,10,4,10), "points"))
```

Comment: Funciona, gracias María

Answer (score -1):

creo que el problema esta donde pones:

`strip.background = element_rect(color="black", fill="#e2ecf1", size=1.5, linetype="solid"),`

Entiendo que si pones mas 'size' en ese parámetro las cajas deberían verse mas grandes, por ejemplo:

`strip.background = element_rect(color="black", fill="#e2ecf1", size=3, linetype="solid"),`

Comment: al cambiar el size lo que hace es incrementar el ancho del contorno pero no la caja, gracias de todas maneras

Comment: tienes razón, quizás es posible hacer lo que quieres utilizando el parámero `height`, por ejemplo así:

`theme(strip.background = element_rect(height = 0.5))`

Comment: Me arroja este error: Error in element_rect(height = 0.5) : unused argument (height = 0.5)